# Are there "events" that you can attach to in Facebook/Twitter

Tags: c#, facebook, twitter

I've been browsing the Facebook API for a way to attach to certain actions/events in Facebook.
But up until now, I didn't find anything that would make sense except the Graph API to retrieve data afterwards.

My goal is quite simple, so simple that I'm a bit confused why I can't find a solution.

Every time when somebody likes or shares a post I posted on my facebook page, I would like to get a notification (in the form of a callback or something) which includes the post and the facebook user that liked or shared my post.

I would like to have something similar when somebody retweets a tweet of mine.
I haven't looked for a solution in Twitter yet, because the Facebook feature is much more important.

Are there any apps/tools or sdk's that could help me achieve this?
Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Regards,
Sven Peeters
Belgium

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Facebook but for Twitter you can subscribe to the streams it provides in its public stream API.

Here is how to do this with Tweetinvi.

```
var stream = Stream.CreateUserStream();

stream.TweetFavouritedByMe += (sender, args) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have favourited a tweet! " + args.Tweet);
};

stream.StartStream();
```

https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/User-Streams

Comment: Thank you for this info but I'm afraid you cannot capture the event that somebody else 'favourited' or 'retweeded' one of you tweets.